# Can i update a YML file automatically in another repo when I make a change

Tags: azure-devops

There are 2 REPOS - REPO1 and REPO2

I have a repo called REPO1 and in there is a yaml file eg pipleines.yml  which runs some tasks to do some tests. The devs use REPO1, when the DEVS update this file in their Main Branch in REPOA is there a way Azure Devops can automatically copy the file into REPOB ?

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to copy it, you can extend your pipeline or template in Repo2 from Repo1. refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for more details

Repo 1 will have something like this

```
# Repo: Contoso/BuildTemplates
# File: common.yml
parameters:
- name: 'vmImage'
  default: 'ubuntu 16.04'
  type: string

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
```

and Repo2 will do this

```
# Repo: Contoso/LinuxProduct
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

Or you could use in any pipeline or stage

extends: template/your-template@other-repo

Comment: only issue i have is the customer wants to have all yml files into a specific repo and the dev also wants the yml file in their repo. issue I have is they both want the yml file in the relevant repos. However if the dev makes changes to that yml file , i need it to be copied over to the other repo on any successful pull request

Comment: So basically , your client wants a copy of the repo? so you could have a master repo with the templates and tag them whenever you finalize changes in master repo. then you can ask your devs to use templates with specific tags and your clients can copy the repo or clone it. To be honest i dont fully understand who is changing the templates and who is using them etc.